# If Russia wins what will happen to the sanctions long term?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, sanctions

Suppose Putin "wins" by

- killing Zelenskyj
- staging a "democratic" election
- instating a new Russian friendly government
- withdrawing all Russian troops

What will happen to the sanctions to Russia long term? Has any country put a strict condition of when sanctions would be lifted?

Comment: It's too speculative to be answered I'd say. Everything is possible. Probably even the world leading politicians have no clue what will happen. Sanctions have no conditions attached.

Comment: *"Everything is possible."* and *"Sanctions have no conditions attached."* basically answers my question. The linked answer also provides as much information as there is it seems. (btw, if you were the one who downvoted, is this a bad question in some way?)